# Show error message in guest subscriber if user already subscribe with that email

Tags: magento, magento2, newsletter, magento2.1

I want to show a custom message if user already subscribed with a email address. 
like

> You are already subscribed. Thank you.

Instead of this message.

[image]

I am using magento2.1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a preference (via di.xml) for the OOTB Controller that handles the Subscription sign-up process (Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php) and in your custom controller's execute method - add the desired logic to check whether/not the customer has already subscribed and handle it accordingly.

[image: Subscription Sign-up Code/Logic]

Comment: means magento2 by default don't check whether user already subscribed or not?. Because every i time i put my email it say "Thank you for your subscription" and each time send me a email.

Comment: @AwaisKhan - On reviewing the OOTB M2 codebase on my localhost (FYI - I'm running on Magento 2.2.1-dev) it looks like there is indeed a check for whether/not the customer is subscribed (Refer Code Lines # 127 - 134)

I'd recommend you take a look at the same file (Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php) on your install to see what the validation logic is. If the validation is missing - you can take the Preference route (as outlined in my post above) or alternatively, you could upgrade to 2.2.x / 2.3.x

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify this simple checking.

Try this -

Go to this path if you haven't override `NewAction.php` file yet `vendor\magento\module-newsletter\Controller\Subscriber` and open `NewAction.php` file.

Replace this code:

```
if ($subscriber->getId() && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
```

With:

```
if($subscriber->getId())
```

That's all.